# How to Loop Through The Properties of a Class and It's Lists (in a C# WP 8.1 WinRT app)?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have tried to figure this out but don't seem to get it.

In the class for a contact some of the property types are lists.

How can I loop through these lists?

I've seen examples of this, but not had success for the lists contained within.

In this case I'm trying to create a runtime app for windows phone 8.1 using c#.

Also is there another way to check if the property type is a list?

Here is the code sample.

```
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Diagnostics;

private async void ShowContacts()
    {

        var contactStore = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync();
        var contacts = await contactStore.FindContactsAsync();

        foreach (var contact in contacts)
        {

            var props = contact.GetType().GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties;

            foreach (var pi in props)
            {

                try
                {

                    Debug.WriteLine("Name: " + pi.Name);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Value: " + pi.GetValue(contact));
                    Debug.WriteLine("Type: " + pi.PropertyType);
                    Debug.WriteLine("\n");

                    if (pi.PropertyType.ToString().Contains("System.Collections.Generic.IList"))
                    {

                        Debug.WriteLine("How to loop through this list?");
                        Debug.WriteLine("\n");

                    }

                }

                catch { }

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: 'pi.GetValue(contact)' cast this into a variable to the correct type, i.e. IList, then iterate over the resultant collection

Comment: I tried to do something like that and it didn't seem to work.  This is what I tried:

                            object test = pi.GetValue(contact);
                            IEnumerable<string> testEnumerable = test as IEnumerable<string>;
                            foreach (string testValue in testEnumerable)
                            {
                                Debug.WriteLine(">>>" + testValue);
                            }

Comment: The set of properties is fixed and documented on MSDN; any reason why you **must** do this via reflection?

Comment: I am hoping to make an app that displays all the entered data for contacts.  If I could loop through all of the values dynamically, it seems easier than hard coding all of the values manually.

Comment: Define 'didn't work' - what happened?

Comment: In the output window when debugging the Debug.WriteLine(">>>" + testValue); only wrote one line shown below.  The expected result was that if the value of the property was a list, then to show all of the values contained in the lists.

Name: DataSuppliers
Value: System.__ComObject
Type: System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.String]


>>>Microsoft account

Comment: That looks right to me, assuming the list has one entry which is a string equal to `"Microsoft account"`. What were you expecting?

Comment: I expect that if a list is detected to then loop through the list and display those values like so:

Name: Emails
Value: System.__ComObject
Type: System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactEmail]

>>>Personal email
>>>Work email
>>>Other email

Answer (score 0):

In the example you give in the comments, casting `DataSuppliers` to `IList<string>` and printing 'Microsoft account' is what I'd expect. However `Emails` is an `IVector<ContactEmail>`, not an `IVector<string>`. What I expect is happening is that this is failing to cast and either throwing, which your code swallows, or being set to null and then dereferenced, which will also throw. That's why you're not seeing the Emails property emitted to the console.

There probably isn't a general-purpose way to do what you're trying to do. Your code will have to deal with every collection type separately, as most of them won't cast to a common type except `IList<object>`, which is rather useless.